# Saving Bot Framework conversation to Azure SQL using Node JS

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, botframework

I can't find any information on how to save conversation data, including images and location data, from the Bot Framework to Azure SQL storage, using Node JS. There is an example in C# but nothing showing this in Node JS. The information on Azure Table Storage and DocumentDB storage options is minimal and appears out of date. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [State In Botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665826/state-in-botframework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the [Node.js Custom-State sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-CustomState). The sample shows how to use Azure Storage and DocumentDb.

Comment: Isn't documentDB superseded by Cosmos DB? Do the same functions apply?

Comment: I haven't tried the sample lately, but it should be compatible. If it's not, you can update it and submit a PR. In any case, the concepts around what to implement in the Bot Framework side remains the same.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Custom-State sample and you are correct. it works with Cosmos DB as documentDb.