# Migration to custom BotState service - checklist?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

After the [announcement](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/), that the out-of-the-box bot state management will be deprecated, we have implemented our own bot state service using following documentation:

- [Manage custom state data with with Azure Cosmos DB for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb)
- [Custom State API Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-CustomState/README.md)
- [Migrated bot state provider but calls to state.botframework.com are still being made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944060/migrated-bot-state-provider-but-calls-to-state-botframework-com-are-still-being)
- [State In Botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665826/state-in-botframework)

Therefore, we can summarize the migration process into following steps:

1. Setup Azure Cosmos DB which will be used to store the bot state data.
2. Update the `Conversation` IoC container to include the `DocumentDbBotDataStore` registrations.
3. Ensure, that `StateClient` type is no longer used since it uses the default out-of-the-box bot state storage. Use the `ConversationData`, `PrivateConversationData` and `UserData` from the `IDialogContext` instead.

After we have implemented above steps we can see that the bot state data is now correctly being stored within our own Cosmos DB. Also, the Bot Channel Emulator no longer reports warnings related to the bot state.

My question is, whether there are other steps which we need to take to ensure, that there wont be any behind the scenes calls to the default deprecated bot state service. Is there something else, which is not too obvious but needs to be considered?

Comment: It looks like you've covered everything.  There are no "behind the scenes calls to the default deprecated bot state service" in the sdk.  If you aren't using activity.GetStateClient(), and you've properly implemented an IBotDataStore.  You're done.

Comment: @EricDahlvang, thanks for the comment. By 'properly implementing an IBotDataStore' you mean registering the `DocumentDbBotDataStore` in the pipeline as demonstrated in [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb#modify-your-bot-code)? If not, then can you please further explain what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @EricDahlvang, quick followup on this one. The steps mentioned in my question were indeed sufficient - the default BotState service is now deprecated and our Cosmos DB store works smoothly in prod. You can re-post your first comment as an answer to this question and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've covered everything. There are no "behind the scenes calls to the default deprecated bot state service" in the sdk. If you are not using activity.GetStateClient(), and you've properly implemented an IBotDataStore. You're done.

This document describes how to use the DocumentDbBotDataStore from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure